# How to do the template recursion in function call?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
template <size_t size_x, size_t size_y>

int func(int(&grid)[size_x][size_y], int s_x, int x)
{
    if (s_x == x)
        return 0;
    else {
        cout << grid[s_x][0] << " " << x << endl;
        s_x++;
        return func(grid, s_x, x);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    while (T > 0) {
        int M, N, x, y, s_x = 0, s_y = 0;
        cin >> M >> N;
        int grid[M][N] = {};
        cin >> x >> y;
        x--;
        y--;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                cin >> grid[i][j];
            }
        }
        int time_r = func(grid, s_x, x);
        cout << time << endl;
        T--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Errors I'm getting:

> no matching function for call to ‘func(int [M][N], int&, int&)’
>                int time_r=func(grid,s_x,x);
>
> note: candidate: template int func(int (&)[size_x][size_y], int, int)
>    int func(int (&grid)[size_x][size_y],int s_x, int x)
>
> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> note:   variable-sized array type ‘long int’ is not a valid template argument
>                int time_r=func(grid,s_x,x);

How to run it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an odd mix of C99 VLAs and C++ templates. The template expects an array with bounds known at compile time, whilst the VLA only knows its bounds at runtime, so this will not work.

You can either go the C way and use a normal (non-template) `func` that takes a pointer and two sizes, or you throw your entire code around and go the C++ way, preferably using vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `M` and `N` are runtime values, and C++ cannot handle array types with dynamic size correctly. You are allowed to create a stack-based array of dynamic size as you did, but that's about it. You cannot pass a pointer to your 2D array around, as C++ forbids you to use the type `int (*)[N]`.

There are a few workarounds to this:

- Do the indexing yourself, passing a flat 1D-array.
- Use an array of pointers, so that all pointer arrays themselves are 1D arrays.
- Use a vector of vectors.
- Fall back to C, which can easily handle runtime array sizes since C99.